# Mono for Android or Java and WCF

Tags: c#, java, wcf, mono, xamarin.android

I am currently using Mono for Android to develop a mobile application. I have been trying to consume a WCF web service by adding a web reference to it but I can't seem to make the call that way. I am now considering to bite the bullet and rewrite the code using Java which I am not as good at as I am with C#.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I consume a WCF webservice using Mono for android.
2. If I am to use java how would I call a method that looks like the one below:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/MyMethod",
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   void MyMethod(CustomObjectFromDataContract c_Object);
   ```

When I make the call I get a MessageBox that says Unhandled exception System.Net.WebException:. When I step into the code I see that the error happens when you call

```
  [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute    ("http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyMethod", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",    ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public void MyMethod([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]   CustomObjectFromDataContract c_Object) {
    this.Invoke("MyMethod", new object[] {
                    c_Object});
    }
```

The invoke is the one throwing the exception.

Comment: "I can't seem to make the call that way" – could you elaborate on this part?

Comment: Please include the exception message and the stack trace - that will help us help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Here are the steps to make this work:
 1. The service has to be a RESTful service
 2. Instead of referencing Localhost (which I was in the generated code) use the IP address of the hosting machine. I think this is because Android runs in Dalvik VM which I suspect has a different local host from the one my Dev computer is using. 
I did that and my service works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Web Reference, some references classes including a client should be generated. 
You can then create an instance of the generated client and call `MyMethod`on the client.

So assuming you are using Visual Studio simply right click you MonoDroid project > Add Web Reference and enter the URL to your WCF service.

To call it you can do the following:
I have added a reference to a service with namespace Example.WebReference

I would then call it in the following way:

```
Example.WebReference.ServiceElement client = new Example.WebReference.ServiceElement();
var output = client.MyMethod(parameter);
```

Hope this helps.